WorkManager - periodic download work on target API 34 => SocketException
I'm using a CoroutineWorker and schedule periodic executions of it. I do not use setForeground as this fails, if the worker is started while my app is not in the foreground and when you use a scheduled worker, you can't ever be sure the app is in the foreground.
I see following issue now:

if my worker is started while my app is running, it can successfully download data and do its work
if it is started while my app is the background, it fails. The worker is started, but internet access fails with following exception.

Exception
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort

This only happens, if my app is the background. Any ideas why this happens and how I can solve that?
Note
In the past, I did the same thing with a foreground service and the alarm manager, but targeting API 34, the alarm manager can't start a foreground service anymore if the app is in the background, so I need to migrate to something alternative like the work manager.
